# Using 12 points in a plane to form triangles

Tags: probability, combinatorics, geometry

Twelve points in the plane are given, such that no three points are on the same line.

Five distinct segments joining pairs of these points are chosen at random, with all $\binom{12}{2} = 66$ such segments equally likely to be chosen. What is the probability that at least one triangle is formed by the chosen segments? (The triangle's three vertices must all come from the original set of 12 points.)

I know that we have to use PIE (because of the "at least") but I don't know how to start.
Anyone want to help?

Answer (score 4):

To choose five edges that make exactly one triangle,
we need a triangle and we need an additional pair of edges that do not form a triangle with any of the other three edges.
In one obvious way of counting successful choices of five edges, which is to count all the ways to choose one triangle and then choose two additional edges, we sometimes get more than one triangle, and these cases will be double-counted, so we do indeed have to use inclusion-exclusion, as you thought.
(When we get only one triangle, the triangle and two non-triangle edges are not interchangeable, so there is no concern we have overcounted those cases.)

There is a one-to-one correspondence between triangles and sets of three points
(where the three points are the vertices of the triangle).
Picking three points from the $12$ possible vertices occurs $\binom{12}3$ ways, so

$$
\text{number of triangles} = \binom{12}3.
$$

Given a triangle, there are $63$ edges remaining to choose from.
We can choose two in any of $\binom{63}2$ ways.
So for the first inclusion step of counting we have
$$
\binom{12}3 \times \binom{63}2.
$$

The only way to have two triangles from just five edges is to have exactly one shared edge and two other points, one for each of the other triangles
(to use as the third vertex).
There are $\binom{12}2$ possibilities for the shared edge,
and from the $10$ remaining points we can choose the other two vertices in
$\binom{10}2$ ways, so the number of possibilities to exclude in the first exclusion step is
$$ \binom{12}2 \times \binom{10}2 . $$

There is no way to get more than two distinct triangles with just five edges, so we can stop here.
There are $\binom{66}5$ equally-likely ways to choose five edges at random, 
so the final answer is

$$
p = \frac{\binom{12}3 \times \binom{63}2 - \binom{12}2 \times \binom{10}2}{\binom{66}5}
\approx 0.04774459411556.
$$

Answer (score 0):

There are $ N = {66 \choose 5}$ choices of 5 edges. To form a triangle, I will need three edges to be $e_{01}, e_{12}, e_{20}$. The first triangle edge is a free choice (66 options), the second triangle edge has 11 options, and the final triangle edge has only 1 option.

We have $63 \times 62$ ways to choose the next two edges. The final two edges may form an additional triangle, but we only want to count those cases once. This only occurs when one of our edges is reused for the second triangle. This occurs ${3\choose 2}9 = 27 $ times for each first triangle we can choose (because there are 9 remaining points and we must use an edge between one of our original 3 points). In the end we have $M = 66 \times 11 \times 1 \times (63 \times 62 - 27)$ ways to form at least one triangle.

So $p = M/N \simeq .315 $.

Comment: I'm bad at counting so please double check my arguments :)

Comment: It seems to me that you are entirely ignoring the problem of over-counting when a choice of edges results in two or more triangles.

Comment: You're right of course. I will attempt to fix that.

Comment: You have counted all the configurations that have two triangles twice, so you need to subtract them once.    As you can't form three triangles, that is all you need.

Comment: Ok, edited to account for over-counting.

Comment: The actual probability is less than $0.05$, as found by simulation. I'm not sure what you are counting, but given the first edge, there are $20$ edges that have a point in common with the first.

Comment: According to the first paragraph there are $66\times11$ possible triangles. Actually there are only $\binom{12}{3} = 66\times11/3.3$, so there's a factor of $3.3$ by which you overcounted. Then the choice of the two non-triangle edges can be done in $\binom{63}{2}=63\times62/2$ ways, so there's a factor of $2$ (in that part of the calculation; it doesn't affect the term $27$). Putting in these corrections, I get approximately $0.0474.$ @DanielMathias is that consistent with the simulation?

Comment: @David The exact value is $\frac{\binom{12}{3}\binom{63}{2}-\frac{\binom{12}{3}\times 27}{2}}{\binom{66}{5}}$ which is $0.0477445941$

Comment: @DanielMathias Right, there was an error in my initial counting. I've posted a summary as a community wiki.

Comment: @DanielMathias The answer by David gives answer different than yours. Also, your answer (in your last comment) takes the exclusion factor as $\frac{(12C3).(3C2* 9)}2$. I am not clear about the divisor $2$ in the fraction. Please elaborate. Also, you have stated to have ascertained probability less than $0.05$, by simulation. Please can you help in details of the simulation, i.e. code etc.

Comment: @jiten Choose a triangle: $\binom{12}{3}$, an edge of that triangle: $\binom{3}{1}$, and one of the $9$ remaining points. This gives a pair of triangles with a common edge. Divide by $2$ because each pair can be chosen in two ways: $\{ABC,BC,D\}\equiv\{BCD,BC,A\}$. Also note $\frac{\binom{12}{3}\times 27}{2}=2970=\binom{12}{3}\binom{10}{2}$, so David's answer is not different. He just found an easier way to express the number of distinct pairs of triangles. Regarding the simulation, the original code was not saved, but would not be difficult to recreate.

Comment: @DanielMathias Thanks a lot. Your reasoning is correct. But,      $\binom{12}3 = 220$, but $\binom{10}2 = 45$, and $\frac{2970}{45}=66 \neq 220$.
Please guide how to make simulation. I need an idea, not clicking.

Comment: @jiten Typo in previous comment, which should have stated: $\frac{\binom{12}{3}\times 27}{2}=2970=\binom{12}{2}\binom{10}{2}$.

Comment: @DanielMathias Please give some inputs regarding (how to set up) simulation, as am unable to get any clues. It would be helpful to many as it helps in pointing out near limits of the answer. Also, have an idea to generalize by finding pattern in 'exclusion terms' for case of 'distinct random edges' being chosen as $6,7$. # of triangles in these cases will differ. However, #terms in inclusion step changes 'too' with #of distinct edges; i.e. $\binom{12}3 \times \binom{63}3$ for $6$ edge case . So, is this idea good for learning purposes? Also for this generalization, simulation will help a lot.

Comment: this [link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/95477) might be of interest to you to generate the twelve points.

Comment: @DanielMathias Have made an attempt in my post at: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3936707/424260. Kindly point out errors of not having suitable divisor there. I mean this in concern to your  first response here to me.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Although, am unable to understand the link much, but request to see my post at: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3936707/424260. Also, for the link's post, can you please post your own answer (comprehensive) there. I mean some points in the answer there are not clear, as why only two points can be considered in a row. Also, why a particular function of $i, i^2 \ mod \ n$ is considered, when collinearity is to be avoided. The author states to take any random quadratic function, but does not give the reason why?

Comment: it's meant to be a link to help you to set up your simulation. Have been quite busy to meet multiple deadlines, might get back to you if i have free time a few days later.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh  Thanks for giving insights into building up a simulation, by giving a post's link that sets up non-collinear points;  a fundamental need here. But, the two doubts still persist, as stated in my last request (comment here). I will wait for your answer there (at the link's post).

Comment: the question is beyond me.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh But hope you will assist in simulation.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Please see my comment on the link for simulation given by you.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Please see my comment at link https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/95477/78009, as not clear about choice of function there. I.e., why only a particular quadratic value of $y_i = x_i^2\ mod\ n$ is needed.